Properly define function from outcome of NSolve and FindRoot
We have the function $\gamma(u,v)$ defined implicitly as the solution of
\begin{align}
  \sin\gamma(u,v)=g\left(u-v\cos\gamma(u,v) \right),
 \end{align}
being $g$ a given function. I can solve for $\gamma$ using NSolve or FindRoot, as for instance
  gt[x_] := x^4; 
  num\[Gamma][(u_)?NumberQ, (v_)?NumberQ] := \[Gamma] /. FindRoot[{gt[u - v*Cos[\[Gamma]]] == Sin[\[Gamma]]}, {\[Gamma], 0.5, 0, Pi}]
  Plot3D[{0, num\[Gamma][u, v]}, {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> Automatic]

however when I want to take derivatives of this $\gamma$ for plotting and further manipulating, simple D does not work. What would be a better approach ? Also, for the case where $g$ is an interpolation function.

We would like to not only take derivatives of $\gamma$ but also integrating and further manipulating, so instead of simply using ImplicitD what I am looking for is to get it as an interpolation function or the like.

Do you know about ImplicitD?

@Domen Thank you. I don't. Does it work with non-analytic, numeric functions ?

$Version

"14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)"

Clear["Global`*"]

eqn = gt[u - v*Cos[γ]] == Sin[γ];

gt[x_] := x^4;

numγ[uv_?NumericQ, vv_?NumericQ] :=
 Module[{u = Rationalize[uv, 0], v = Rationalize[vv, 0]},
  γ /. FindRoot[{gt[u - v*Cos[γ]] == Sin[γ]}, 
    {γ, 1/2, 0, Pi},
    WorkingPrecision -> 15]]

As suggested by Domen, use ImplicitD
dγu[u_, v_] = (ImplicitD[eqn, γ, u] // FullSimplify) /. 
   γ -> numγ[u, v]

(* 1/(Cos[numγ[u, v]]/(4 (u - v Cos[numγ[u, v]])^3) - 
 v Sin[numγ[u, v]]) *)

dγv[u_, v_] = (ImplicitD[eqn, γ, v] // FullSimplify) /. 
   γ -> numγ[u, v]

(* 1/(-(1/(4 (u - v Cos[numγ[u, v]])^3)) + 
 v Tan[numγ[u, v]]) *)

Plot3D[Evaluate@dγu[u, v], {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1},
 Exclusions -> {u == v},
 ClippingStyle -> None,
 PlotRange -> {-1.5, 5},
 WorkingPrecision -> 15,
 PlotPoints -> 50,
 MaxRecursion -> 5,
 AxesLabel -> Automatic]


Plot3D[Evaluate@dγv[u, v], {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1},
 Exclusions -> {u == v},
 ClippingStyle -> None,
 PlotRange -> {-4, 2},
 WorkingPrecision -> 15,
 PlotPoints -> 50,
 MaxRecursion -> 5,
 AxesLabel -> Automatic]



Thank you. In version  13.1 it's quite slow, tho. I also wanted to avoid ImplicitD because if we want to integrate instead of differentiate, or perform any other operation, it will not be direct as with for instance an interpolation function.

This is an abusing of NDSolveValue to solve non-differential equation by adding D[γ[u, v], v] to both sides of the equation.
Works well also with derivation or integration of $\gamma$.
gt[x_] := x^4

gama = NDSolveValue[
    gt[u - v*Cos[γ[u, v]]] + D[γ[u, v], v] == 
     Sin[γ[u, v]] + D[γ[u, v], v], γ, {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}] // Quiet;

Plot3D[gama[u, v], {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All]

Plot3D[Derivative[0, 1][gama][u, v], {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All]

Plot3D[NIntegrate[gama[u, v], {u, 0, 1}], {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All]




Perhaps this?:
\[Gamma]IFN = 
 FunctionInterpolation[num\[Gamma][u, v], {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}]

Then
Plot3D[{0, num\[Gamma][u, v], \[Gamma]IFN[u, v]},
 {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> Automatic]


